# Redux state props undefined and ComponentDidMount not firing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my localhost react-node app, when I hit the `Movies.js` page, the app would make an api call to a `{localhost}/api/movies` node endpoint (I am using `redux-thunk` middleware btw).

It would then return a json to `this.props.movies.displayedMovies` (entrypoint is `componentDidMount()`), and then pass that to `render()`.

Since then, the only change is I've added another reducer `MusicReducer` and used redux's `combinedReducer(..)` to configure store.

Now, the Movies page is rendering blank because console is returning `Cannot read property 'displayedMovies' of undefined` and componentDidMount doesnt seem to be called.

Not sure what the problem is. Below is the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Movies.js container

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as moviesActions from '../actions/MoviesActions'

import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import ResultsBar from '../components/ResultsBar'
import Grid from '../components/Grid'
import * as utils from '../utils/utils.js'
import style from '../style/App.css'

class Movies extends Component {

  handleSearch(e) {
    this.props.moviesActions.filterMovies(e.target.value)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.moviesActions.fetchMovies()
  }

  render() {
    let { displayedMovies } = this.props.movies

    return (
      <div>
      <NavBar onChange={this.handleSearch.bind(this)} type={0}/>
      <br/>
      <ResultsBar count={displayedMovies.length} type={0}/>
      <Grid
          gridData={JSON.stringify(displayedMovies)}
          gridCell_width={140}
          gridCell_height={200}
          type={0}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    movies: state.movies
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    moviesActions: bindActionCreators(moviesActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Movies)
```

MoviesActions.js action

```
import {
  REQUEST_MOVIES,
  RECEIVE_MOVIES,
  FILTER_MOVIES,
  SORT_MOVIES
} from '../constants/Page'
import * as utils from '../utils/utils.js'

function requestMovies() {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_MOVIES
  }
}

function receiveMovies(json) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_MOVIES,
    movies: json
  }
}

export function fetchMovies() {

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestMovies())

    utils.callApi('/api/movies')
      .then(items => {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          data.push({
            tmdb_id: items[i].id, 
            imdb_id: items[i].imdb_id, 
            title: items[i].title, 
            poster_path: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + items[i].poster_path,
            backdrop_path: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + items[i].backdrop_path, 
            url_path: items[i].url_path, 
            release_date: items[i].release_date, 
            runtime: items[i].runtime, 
            revenue: items[i].revenue,
            overview: items[i].overview,
            tagline: items[i].tagline, 
            link: 'http://www.imdb.com/title/' + items[i].imdb_id
          });
        }
        dispatch(receiveMovies(data))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

}

export function filterMovies(searchTerm) {
  return {
    type: FILTER_MOVIES,
    searchTerm
  }
}

export function sortMovies(sortOption) {
  return {
    type: SORT_MOVIES,
    sortOption
  }
}
```

index.js reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  BOOKS,
  COMICS,
  MOVIES,
  MUSIC,
  PODCASTS,
  TV
} from '../constants/Page'
import moviesReducer from './MoviesReducer'
import musicReducer from './MusicReducer'

export default combineReducers({
  moviesReducer,
  musicReducer
})
```

MoviesReducer.js reducer

```
import {
  REQUEST_MOVIES,
  RECEIVE_MOVIES,
  FILTER_MOVIES,
  SORT_MOVIES
} from '../constants/Page'

const initialState = {
  movies: [],
  displayedMovies: []
}

export default function movie(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_MOVIES:
      return {
        ...state
      }

    case RECEIVE_MOVIES:
      let movies = action.movies
      return {
        ...state,
        movies,
        displayedMovies: movies
      }

    case FILTER_MOVIES:
      let displayedMovies = state.movies.filter(movie => {
        if (movie.title.toLowerCase().includes(action.searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
          return true
        }
        return false
      })
      return {
        ...state,
        displayedMovies,
        displayedMovies: displayedMovies
      }

    case SORT_MOVIES:
      let sortDisplayedMovies
      switch(action.sortOption) {
        case 'Alphabetical':
          sortDisplayedMovies = state.displayedMovies.sort((a,b)=> {
            var a1 = a.title.toLowerCase();
            var b1 = b.title.toLowerCase();
            return a1<b1 ?-1:a1> b1? 1 :0;
          })
          break;
        case 'Oldest':
          sortDisplayedMovies = state.displayedMovies.sort((a,b)=> {
            return new Date(a.release_date).getTime() - new Date(b.release_date).getTime();
          })
          break;
        case 'Newest':
          sortDisplayedMovies = state.displayedMovies.sort((a,b)=> {
            return new Date(b.release_date).getTime() - new Date(a.release_date).getTime();
          })
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        sortDisplayedMovies,
        displayedMovies: sortDisplayedMovies
      }

    default:
      return state
  }

}
```

configureStore.js store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index'

export default function configureStore() {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );

  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the problem with your `mapStateToProps`.

Because you have defined your `combineReducers` as below

```
export default combineReducers({
  moviesReducer,
  musicReducer
})
```

which is same as doing below

```
export default combineReducers({
  movieReducer:movieReducer,
  musicReducer:musicReducer
})
```

your movie state is within

```
state.movieReducer.movies
```

which means in your `mapStateToProps` you have to inject correct value like so

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    movies: state.movieReducer.movies
  }
}
```